# How to disable the default open menu effect in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, effect, menubar

By default in Flex 3.2, clicking on an item in a MenuBar navigator results in a menu rolling out over a small period of time.

How would I disable this and make the menu pop out instantly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `Menu#openDuration` style to 0.